# Calculate total number of pixel in an image

Tags: javascript, php, steganography

How do I calculate the total number of pixel of an image before uploading it to the server? I'm using steganography with PHP and sometimes the number of pixel of a selected image isn't enough to contain the message to hide. I'm looking for a way in javascript or PHP to know the number of pixels in an image to avoid problems when image is processed.

Comment: In php, using [getimagesize](http://php.net/getimagesize) and multiplying the width by height returned should give the number of pixels.

Comment: If you want to check this on the client side before uploading, then you can do this using the HTML5 File API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images shows a basic example to create an img element to show a “preview” of the selected image, and once you got it loaded into an actual image element, you can check its dimensions like you would with any “normal” image object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<?php

[$width, $height] = getimagesize('your_image.jpg');
$numPixels = $width * $height;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for a client side and a server side method. I will try your code. What I need to do is to embed AES payload that is holding a images converted into data URI. Sometimes the images have less pixel than needed So I'm looking for a way to calculate the input images pixel and the needed pixels to embed the payload